# False convergence result

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I wrote a proof below that if A(n) is decreasing and lim A(n) = 0 for some sequence, then the corresponding series must converge. I know this is false, with the harmonic series as a counterexample, so I want to know where I messed up.

Consider a sequence A(n) and its sequence of partial sums S(n) = A(n) + A(n-1) ... A(1). Assume that lim A(n) = 0. By the Cauchy criterion, the sum of the sequence S(n) converges iff for every E there exists an N such that for m>n> N, we get |S(m)-S(n)| < E.

So,

|S(m)-S(n)| = |A(m) + A(m-1) +...+ A(n)| <= |A(m)| + |A(m-1)| +... + |A(n+1)| <= (m-n)|A(n)|

Chose N such that for every n > N, |A(n)|<(E/(m-n)). Then we get that |S(m)-S(n)| < E

Any help is appreciated

Comment: The problem is that $m$ isn't fixed here, so your $(m-n)$ term can grow arbitrarily large (thus making $\frac{\epsilon}{m-n}$ arbitrarily small), so you don't necessarily have the inequalities in the final line holding for all $n>N$.

Comment: Can you explain that?

Comment: The definition of Cauchy is that for **all** $m,n>N$, $|S(m)-S(n)| < \epsilon$, or in your proof $|A(n)| < \frac{\epsilon}{m-n}$. But by making $m$ 'much bigger' than $n$, $\frac{\epsilon}{m-n}$ becomes very small.

This is similar to the difference between: 

"For all $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $N$ such that $n,m>N$ implies $|a_n - a_m| < \epsilon$" and

"There exists $N$ such that for all $\epsilon > 0$ $n,m>N$ implies $|a_n - a_m| < \epsilon$" since by varying $|m-n|$ you can intuitively think of this as effectively changing $\epsilon$ and making it much smaller.